# dynamically add imagebutton programmatically Android

Tags: android

I am getting dynamic length of the string array and I want to display images in the imagebutton and that too in horizontal view as I had added button but it shows in the vertical layout. This is my code:

```
for (int i =0;i<adapt_objmenu.image_array.length;i++){
    ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(myrefmenu);
        b1.setId(100 + i);

       // b1.setText(adapt_objmenu.city_name_array[i]);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i > 0) {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, b1.getId() - 1);
        }   
        b1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        relative.addView(b1);

    //relate.addView(b1, i,  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));

    //height = height+80;
}
```

Comment: You do realise you're setting `RelativeLayout.BELOW`, whereas `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF` would make more sense, if I understand your question correctly?

Comment: ok i got that but how to set image on the imagebutton that's the main question

Comment: you mean you want to set image after added in to `RelativeLayout` for `ImageButton`.

Comment: after 3rd line from the code i want to add the bitmap image to the imagebutton but dont know how to please help

Comment: BAD, bad idea ... why don't you use `ListView` instead ? 'ListView' is optimized for such things ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your Third Line for set Image for ImageButton.

```
  for (int i =0;i<adapt_objmenu.image_array.length;i++){
     ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(myrefmenu);
        b1.setId(100 + i);
         b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
       // b1.setText(adapt_objmenu.city_name_array[i]);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i > 0) {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, b1.getId() - 1);
        }   
        b1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        relative.addView(b1);

//relate.addView(b1, i,  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));

//height = height+80;



}
```

Comment: actually i want to set one static image as the imagebutton's image as i want to show it as paging control just like white dots on the top to display length of the array that indicates the no. of pages

Comment: your image are in Drawable folder or in some where else.If in Drawable folder then you can use `mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Comment: Then you should Prepare array of Image Resource Id and use it for apply in your loop.